# Model is dissapearing when I am using TransformControls react three drei

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

[Code Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fB4r5.png)

[Code Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrG5A.png)

Here is the code I have written. I couldn't find any issue or error to fix this problem.

I am trying to moving the plane by x axis and z axis using TransformControls. But when I am writing this TransformControls the model dissapears.